# Binance API returns with: APIError(code=-1013): Filter failure: PRICE_FILTER

Tags: python, binance

`APIError(code=-1013): Filter failure: PRICE_FILTER`

I can't figure out what the error is. I am sending this request:

```
 order = self.client.create_order(
                symbol=symbol,
                side=side,
                timeInForce=TIME_IN_FORCE_GTC,
                type=order_type,
                quantity=quantity,
                price=price
            )
```

It usually works but occasionally I get the before mentioned error.

Quantity and Price were in my case:

```
 quantity = 0.0003 
 price= 40022.4
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

This error occures when your price parameter does not comply with symbol's price filter's specification. Price value needs to satisfy at least three conditions, which are;

- `minPrice` defines the minimum price/stopPrice allowed; disabled on `minPrice == 0.`
- `maxPrice` defines the maximum price/stopPrice allowed; disabled on `maxPrice == 0.`
- `tickSize` defines the intervals that a price/stopPrice can be increased/decreased by; disabled on `tickSize == 0.`

To get price filter information for any symbol you need to use `GET /api/v3/exchangeInfo` API. Anyone uses `python-binance` library can use the following method to get `PRICE_FILTER` information for the requested symbol.

```
def get_price_filter(self, symbol):
    data_from_api = self.__client.get_exchange_info()
    symbol_info = next(filter(lambda x: x['symbol'] == symbol, data_from_api['symbols']))
    return next(filter(lambda x: x['filterType'] == 'PRICE_FILTER', symbol_info['filters']))
```

where `self.__client` is type of `binance.client.Client`

Answer (score 2):

From the [error docs](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/errors.md):

> *"Filter failure: PRICE_FILTER"*
>
> *price is too high, too low, and/or not following the tick size rule for the symbol.*

**Solution**: Adjust the `price` value so that it follows the rules set in the filter. Each pair can have different filter values. See the [Filter](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#filters) section of the REST API docs for more info.

Answer (score 2):

This error can come from specifying too high a precision in the price

Comment: No, this error certainly not related with precision at all. There is another error code for bad precision which is `-1111 BAD_PRECISION`

Comment: maybe they are returning the wrong error code.  Anyway, this is how I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

The "price" data must be a maximum of 5 characters including the period for CARDANO(ADAUSDT).
Like this  >>> price= 2.270  <<<

I did this.

```
def LimitOrderFunc(result):
    try:
        print("---BUY ORDERL---LİMİT ORDER---")
        order = client.order_limit_buy(
            symbol='ADAUSDT',
            quantity=5,
            price=result,
            recvWindow=1000)
    except Exception as e:
        print("an exception occured - {}".format(e))
        return False

return True   


result=""
.
..
...

temporary=myTargetPrice(calculatingData)   # this line return more digit float data.
temporary=str(temporary)                   #Type conversion is done in this line to string data.
counter=0
while counter<5:
   global result
   result+=temporary[counter]
   counter+=1

LimitOrderFunc(result)
result=""
```