# binance api, my sell function is not working but my buy function is working

Tags: python, python-3.x, binance

I am working with the Binance API and created a buy function which buys BTC at a specific price. But when I try to sell it at a specific price, I have a lot of errors and I don't know why.

My errors are :

```
Binance API: APIError(code=-1111): Precision is over the maximum defined for this asset.
```

OR

```
Binance API returns with: APIError(code=-1013): Filter failure: PRICE_FILTER
```

In this example, I printed the price at which I would like to sell my BTC as well as the quantity and it gave me:

Price:23131.845 QTY:20

I tried to ignore the commas problems with a loop but it didn't work:

There is my buy function that works:

```
def putOrderBuy_at_price(self, symbol, amount, price):
        monney_price = self.client.get_symbol_ticker(symbol=symbol)
    # Calculate how much ETH $200 can buy
        print(monney_price['price'])
        i = 15
        
        while i != 0:
            try:     
                buy_quantity = round(amount / float(price), i)
                print("-----------", buy_quantity)
                #ETHUSDT
                buy_order = self.client.create_order(          
                    symbol = symbol,
                    price = price,
                    quantity = buy_quantity,
                    side = self.client.SIDE_BUY,
                    type = self.client.ORDER_TYPE_LIMIT,              
                    timeInForce = self.client.TIME_IN_FORCE_GTC)
                
                return(buy_order)
            except Exception:
                print(i)
                i -= 1

        print(buy_quantity)
        # buy_order = self.client.create_order(          
        #             symbol = symbol,
        #             price = price,
        #             quantity = buy_quantity,
        #             side = self.client.SIDE_BUY,
        #             type = self.client.ORDER_TYPE_LIMIT,              
        #             timeInForce = self.client.TIME_IN_FORCE_GTC)
```

There is my sell function that doesn't work:

```
def putOrderSell_at_price(self, symbol, amount, price):
        monney_price = self.client.get_symbol_ticker(symbol=symbol)

        i = 10

        print("ahsaiaa", price, amount)
        
        while i != 0:
            try:
                buy_quantity = round(amount / float(price), i)

                #ETHUSDT
                buy_order = self.client.create_order(          
                    symbol = symbol,
                    price = price,
                    quantity = buy_quantity,
                    side = self.client.SIDE_SELL,
                    type = self.client.ORDER_TYPE_LIMIT,              
                    timeInForce = self.client.TIME_IN_FORCE_GTC)
                return(buy_order)

            except Exception:   
                print(i)
                i -= 1

        print("vente faite")
```

and I call them like this:

```
            buy = self.putOrderBuy_at_price(symbol, self.qty_eur, price_actual) #le principal
            sell = self.putOrderSell_at_price(symbol, self.qty_eur, float(price_actual)*1.1) #l ordre de vente
```

Comment: `i have a lot of error` where? show them to us. it's useless to tell us there's errors but not show us; do you seriously think we want to try to figure out how to run your code so that we can see those same errors? That's unreasonable to expect of us; you can take a second to paste in the error and save us loads of time.

Comment: is it better? :) and sorry for my misstake

Comment: So what do you understand about those errors? Did you look them up? If not, you have to do that before posting here anyway, so you should

Comment: The important thing show trade and price quantity, basically the data you are submitting and then what is binance reverting to you. AFAIK code here is unnecessary,

Comment: of cours i did, its for that i did my loop

Comment: done! does it seem clear now? and thank you for your patience

Comment: Are any of the answers here relevant to the "PRICE_FILTER" error? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67018819/binance-api-returns-with-apierrorcode-1013-filter-failure-price-filter

Comment: Also API documentation on filters is here: https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/delivery/en/#filters

Comment: i already tried this :(